# How many SETs are possible in 6 cards

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

A SET deck consists of 81 cards. Each card contains a set of symbols with four attributes:
color (red, green, purple), shading (empty, striped, or solid), shape (oval, squiggle, or rhombus),
and number of symbols (one, two, or three).

Each symbol on any one card is identical, and all the
cards are unique. A SET occurs when three cards satisfy the following property for each of the
four attributes:
They are either:

All the same (all three striped) or they are all different (red, green, and purple symbols).

In order for three cards to form a SET, they must satisfy this property for all four attributes. For
example, if three cards contain two ovals and a squiggle, then they are automatically not a set,
regardless of their other attributes.

Find the maximum possible number of SETs in 6 distinct
cards. One card may appear in more than one set.

(A) 2 (B) 3 (C) 4 (D) 5 (E) 6

So first I changed everything into 1's, 2's, and 3's. So, green, striped, rhombus, one = 2231.
For it to form a set, either all three in one place are different, or the same. WLOG let the first one be 1111.
Then, you could have 1122.
Then, 1133 makes (1111,1122,1133).
If we add 2222 and 3333:

(2222,1111,3333)

Finally, 3311:
(1133,3311,2222)

This gives 3.

There isn't an answer so I'm asking for you guys to check. Thanks.

Comment: I did not find a solution to this on math stack exchange, but I did on puzzling stack exchange. There, they say the answer is three, and give a good description of the solution. Here is a link: [Puzzling.Stackexchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/27772/the-maximum-number-of-sets-with-six-cards)